# Pass multiple JSON data in Request Body of Postman and Get into Java Rest API using Jersy(JXRS)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, postman

I want to get multiple JSON data which I am passing into Postman in Body as Json format.

If I am passing single json data like : "{"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"}" so I can get it in my Java API mentioned as below :

```
@Path("patient")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getPatient(Patient patient) {
System.out.println(patient.getFirstName());
System.out.println(patient.getLastName());
return "ok";
}
```

It is working properly. But if I want to pass data like [{"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"},{"firstName":"shreya","lastName":"patel"}]

and getting in API like below :

```
@Path("patientDetail")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getPatientDetails(@RequestBody List<Patient> patient) {
for (Patient p : patient) {
System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
System.out.println(p.getLastName());
}
return "ok";
}
```

When I am hitting request from postman by passing multiple JSON data as I have mentioned, even getPateintDetails method is not calling, how to pass and get multiple json data in Rest API. Please give me the solution or reference link for the same.

Comment: Please add error codes and exceptions you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Check this small working example which are looking for..

**Track.java**

```
public class Track {
    String title;
    String singer;
    //getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
    }
}
```

**JSONService.java**

```
@Path("/json/check")
public class JSONService {
    @POST
    @Path("/postManyAsString")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String createManyTrackInJSON(String jsonStr) throws Exception {
        JSONObject inputObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        if(inputObject.get("tracks") instanceof JSONObject)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) inputObject.get("tracks");
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("title"));
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("singer"));
        }
        else if(inputObject.get("tracks") instanceof JSONArray)
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) inputObject.get("tracks");
            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println(jsonObject.get("title"));
                System.out.println(jsonObject.get("singer"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(inputObject.get("tracks"));
        }
        return "Okay";
    }
}
```

**URL: http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/json/check/postMany
input data:**

```
[{
    "title" : "hai1",
    "singer" : "sree1"
},
{
    "title" : "hai2",
    "singer" : "sree2"
},
{
    "title" : "hai3",
    "singer" : "sree3"
}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying exactly like this, but json format was wrong

Comment: now the problem got resolved? what is the format of data you are posting?

Comment: {
 "patient":[
  {"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"},
  {"firstName":"shreya","lastName":"patel"}
  ]
}

Comment: Now I have one another list inside Patient class which is List<PatientDetails> patientDetails. I am getting it in that method like : for (Patient p : patient) { System.out.println(p.getFirstName()); System.out.println(p.getLastName()); List<PatientDetails> patientDetails = p.getPatientDetails(); for(PatientDetails pd : patientDetails){ Sysout(pd.getChargeAmount()); Sysout(pd.getItemNumber()); } } and my json is like : {"patient":[ {"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"}, {"patientDetails":[ {"chargeAmount":"riya","itemNumber":"soni"} ]} ]}. But getting exception in that.

Comment: please try to add sample Patient and PatientDetails classes in the post.. also add the input you are sending and the exception you got.. it would be easy to check the problem instead of reading it from comments..

Comment: @RiyaSoni I have edited my answer with the post method which accepts your input format json object, please test with that and let me know

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. But as of now, I am using small json that's why if we get it as String in our method, it is easy to iterate that json. But in my project, json will be bery big. Can you give me solution in that context of list<POJO CLASS> ? Means in the context of class, we need to map json with our pojo.

Answer (score -1):

Try the JSON by passing in the below format.

```
{
  "data" : [
    {"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"}, 
    {"firstName":"shreya","lastName":"patel"}
 ]
}
```

Parse the JSON and get the data variable first and use it to get each object in the array.

Comment: yes, correct. This format is working properly. I have used wrong format

Comment: But, I have one another list inside Patient class which is List<PatientDetails> patientDetails. I am getting it in that method like : for (Patient p : patient) {
System.out.println(p.getFirstName());
System.out.println(p.getLastName());
List<PatientDetails> patientDetails = p.getPatientDetails();
for(PatientDetails pd : patientDetails){
Sysout(pd.getChargeAmount());
Sysout(pd.getItemNumber());
} } and my json is like : 
{"patient":[
{"firstName":"riya","lastName":"soni"},
{"patientDetails":[
{"chargeAmount":"riya","itemNumber":"soni"}
]}
]}. But getting exception in that.

Comment: May be you are parsing it wrong in the code and can you please post the code and the exception?

Comment: May be this JSON format is wong, I need to add "patientDetails" with firstname and lastname. Is it so ?

Comment: That would make more sense. The json format is good, Its just inappropriate in your case.

Comment: yes, thanks you for your solution. If I am taking another list in Patient POJO, then any extra configurations will be needed, like @XmlRootElement  ?